# A elegant solution to this repetitive code?

Tags: gml

I have this code, but it just looks like there should be a way to do it in fewer lines/code.

```
if (TargetX > Origin[0] + Range) TargetX = Origin[0] + Range;
if (TargetY > Origin[1] + Range) TargetY = Origin[1] + Range;
if (TargetX < Origin[0] - Range) TargetX = Origin[0] - Range;
if (TargetY < Origin[1] - Range) TargetY = Origin[1] - Range;
```

I'm using a language called GML, but this should be universal as long as the solution doesn't have any really specific built-in functions.

Comment: Hi! I'm not familiar with GML, but from a quick search and the tag description I cannot understand the tag Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not easy to answer your question. For sure, you can [dry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) your code up.

Observe that you can simplify your call as:

```
abs(target - origin) < range
```

This tells you if, in both directions, your target is in the range `origin ± range`. Now that you know this, you need to take action if your target is outside range. This can be simplified again: you just need to check if `target` is greater than `origin` or viceversa.

Finally, you should either use arrays for both target and origin, or define a function that you may call. Apparently, range is identical every time.

You might use a function:

```
f(target, origin, range) {
    if (abs(target - origin) > range) {
        target = (target - origin) < 0 ? target-range : target+range
    }
}
```

Now it looks like that your code has become longer, but is also more easy to maintain: reduce the risk of writing `>` instead of `<`, change the function once to change all checks and so on.